# How do I output the contents of a function to a discord channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Desired output on a discord channel using the PrettyTables module:
[image]

Hey everyone, I'm new to Discord bot development and need some helpful advice on what steps I can take to ensure my table, which should look something like the image above, is displayed properly on a discord channel.

For context I'm appending items to three empty lists I initialized at the beginning of my program and used the PrettyTable module to organize my list row-by-row for organization sake. Here's the error message I'm brought to on the console whenever I'm done executing the add slash command.

Cheers!

Comment: `await context.channel.send(display_list())` - here you are calling function `display_list()`, but is does not return any value. Ultimately, `await context.channel.send(None)` is called - with empty parameter, and therefore you have `400 Cannot send an empty message` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord acts really oddly towards spacing, and I highly recommend not using a pretty-print module to format your text. I believe that you would be much better off using [Discord Embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed). To create a table effect, you can just create three Embed Fields that are all inline. Your Embed Fields can serve as the columns in your table.

Here’s a short example of something that you might want to do:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Homework Planner")
embed.add_field(name="Course Name", value="225\n174\n105", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Assignment", value="Lab reading\nZybook reading\nEngineering write-up", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Due Date", value="June 18th\nJune 21st\nJune 29th", inline=True)
await context.channel.send(embed=embed)
```